An error occurred when compiling Pytorch from source code
I'm trying to compile Pytorch from source code, and encountered this problem which I can't figure out how to deal with it.
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/crt/math_functions.h:10554,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/crt/common_functions.h:303,
                 from /usr/local/cuda/bin/../targets/x86_64-linux/include/cuda_runtime.h:117,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/include/c++/9/cmath:45:15: fatal error: math.h: No such file or directory
   45 | #include_next <math.h>
      |               ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

My machine is equipped with 2 Nvidia 3090 GPUs,
The system is:
Ubuntu: 20.04.2
anaconda3
Python 3.8
cuda-11.8
There are different versions of cuda on the machine, so I added these in ~/.bashrc:
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-11.8
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin:$PATH

I'd like to use the compiled pytorch to test YOLOv5.
I've put the pytorch folder right at home directory /home/lyy.
I have followed the official guide to compile Pytorch, namely these steps:
conda create -n yolo python=3.8
conda activate yolo
conda install astunparse numpy ninja pyyaml mkl mkl-include setuptools cmake cffi typing_extensions future six requests dataclasses
conda install -c pytorch magma-cuda110
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.6
conda install cuda cuda-nvcc -c nvidia/label/cuda-11.6.0

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LDFLAGS="-L$CONDA_PREFIX/lib $LDFLAGS"

export TRACE_KERNEL=1
export USE_CUDNN=1
export DEBUG=1

export CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib:$CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX:-"$(dirname $(which conda))/../"}

cd pytorch
python setup.py install

The wheel I'm trying to build is torch-1.12.0a0+git8c4ef23.
I don't know how to deal with the error and have searched for the solutions online, but none takes effect.
I've tried to add these env:
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=

But the error remains.
Frustrated.

Do you have libstdc++-9-dev installed?

Searching for "fatal error: math.h: No such file or directory" turns up hundreds of relevant results from Reddit and Stack Overflow.
